# How can I implement facebook-like avatar upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, file-upload

On facebook, if you click on edit picture, you get a menu that offers the option `Upload photo`. I want to implement something similar on my website. I want the browser's file upload dialog to appear once I click on `Upload photo`, and I'd like it to automatically be submitted once the user selects a picture. How should this be implemented?

A colleague suggested a hidden div that has with an input field of type file, and to automatically trigger the click event when the user clicks on `Upload photo`, and then, to listen for the `change` event on the file field, and submit the form using jquery. What do you think?

Comment: What have you tried? This is too broad a question, try Googling for solutions first - they are out there.

Comment: @Jon, I don't want to blindly implement things. As you can see from the message, I already posted an idea as to how I think it could be done, but I want to see if something better exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into a file uploader plugin such as [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/). Plupload has several nice features specifically for the uploading of images such as:

1. Lower the quality of the image to a specific percentage of the original
2. Resize the image to specific dimensions if possible

Also, I am pretty sure that plupload has a built in option to automatically submit once the user has selected an image.